# How to run command before service starts up with saltstack

Tags: arangodb, salt-stack

I am using saltstack to start up an arangodb instance on a centos7 machine. I would like to start it up with a custom password, so I would like to run `ARANGODB_DEFAULT_ROOT_PASSWORD=<my password> arango-secure-installation` after the arangodb 3.5 rpm is installed on the machine but before it starts up, because you can only set the password while it is not running. I'm not sure how to do that exactly with salt stack, but I assume it has something to do with the cmd.run salt function.

Here's the installation/startup salt code I have:

```
arangodb_3_server:
  pkg.latest:
    - refresh: True
    - pkgs:
      - arangodb3
    cmd.run:
      - name: "ARANGODB_DEFAULT_ROOT_PASSWORD={{ arangodb.get('ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD', '') }} arango-secure-installation"
  service.running:
    - name: arangodb3
    - enable: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf
```

So I'm wondering can I basically just put the secure-installation command somewhere to accomplish this? From what I've tried I've only gotten compilation errors or it doesn't set the password.

Answer (score 0):

in Ubuntu I used policy-rc.d to return a non-zero code. I did not find an alternative solution for CentOS. you can stop the service using service.dead after installation, then run your command with cmd.run, and then start service by service.running

Comment: My 2 cents: this will work but wouldn't be idempotent. The service will be stopped every time as is. You may want to use a requisite of some type.

Comment: @pier you're right. maybe we can handle this with grains. if we add a grain after the first time and check if the grain is present skip the restarting part.